# manage.py flag to force unattended command?

Tags: python, django, django-manage.py

I am reading this tutorial: [Installing and Configuring Graphite and Statsd on an Ubuntu 12.04 VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/installing-and-configuring-graphite-and-statsd-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps)

and I am working to automatize everything is possible then there is one step of this tutorial that is giving me crazy:

> Next, we will configure the Graphite database. Go to the Graphite
>   webapp directory and run the database script:

```
cd /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/
sudo python manage.py syncdb
```

As you see, we have to run the manage.py and when I run syncdb ask about a creation of superuser. How can I avoid that? I would like to run these sending all parameters to make an automatic script.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [the `--noinput` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---noinput) to disable those prompts for [the `syncdb` command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-syncdb).

> `--noinput`
>
> Use the `--noinput` option to suppress all user prompting, such as “Are you sure?” confirmation messages. This is useful if `django-admin.py` is being executed as an unattended, automated script.